# Get resource folder in java war file

Tags: java, file, file-io, war, keyczar

I'm creating a REST webservice that uses keyczar for encryption. I've generated both public and private keys and placed them under src/main/resources/RSA.

To instantiate the encrypter I need to pass to it the location of the files like `Crypter crypterPrivate = new Crypter(PATH_RSA + "/private");` but I'm having problems with the RSA folder location when I deploy the war file.

I've tried some stuff I've googled like InputStream but it is not this case since I don't want to pass any file but the RSA folder location. Also have tried several different folders like `/WEB-INF/classes/RSA` (it's where is located in war file).

Any tips? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If keyczar can take a URL for its key location then `this.getClass().getResource("/RSA/private")` will give you a suitable URL.  If it requires a native file path then you'll have to use

```
ServletContext ctx = // ...
String pathToKey = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/RSA/private");
```

Exactly how you get hold of the `ServletContext` depends on your toolkit.  Note that this will only work if the WAR file is expanded on disk when you deploy it, it won't work if the app is running directly from the compressed WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this file via the classpath.

```
URL resourceUrl = URL.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/RSA");
File resourceFile = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
```

Comment: this way resourceUrl is null. If `URL resourceUrl = URL.class.getResource("");` I get the full path to the class

Comment: Is your /WEB-INF/classes/RSA in class path?

Comment: ` <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Java version of Keyczar doesn't support this functionality, but I believe someone submitted a small patch in their issue tracker to add it:

http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/issues/detail?id=55

```
KeyczarClassLoaderReader reader = new KeyczarClassLoaderReader(PATH_RSA + "/private");
Crypter crypterPrivate = new Crypter(reader);
```